# if condition in razor view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Following is my view page

```
        <table class="travTableCont width_full" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
@if(Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0)
        {   
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#header").hide();
         });
            </script>      
           <tr style="text-align:center;">
            <label>No data is Available</label>
           </tr> 
        }                            
<thead id="header">
<tr>                
    <th style="width: 50%;">
        @Model.lstCommonLabels.lblCurrentOwnership
    </th>                
    <th>
        @Model.lstCommonLabels.lblCount
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>            
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
<div id="pagecontent" style=" overflow:auto;height:300px;">
<table class="travTableCont width_full" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody class="travTableContent">
            @foreach (var item in Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities)
            {                    
                <tr>
                <td class="tdo" style="width: 30%;">@item.CurrentOwnership</td>
                <td class="tdt"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail('@item.CurrentOwnership');">@item.cnt</a></td>
                </tr>
            }                
    </tbody>        
    </table>
</div>
```

in above code i gave the if condition, `@if(Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0)`
it is working when `lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0` and also when `lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count!=0`. i want to display table header when `lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count!=0`.

Comment: When `Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0` is true, you hide your header and output `No data is Available` (invalid HTML, should be in <tr><td></td></tr>). What do you want to change and how?

Comment: this condition works when Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0 is true and also when it is false.how can rectify it are you mean to say the if condition which i gave is wrong?

Comment: is this condition is right? @if(Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count==0)

Comment: Did you try to analyze what is happening to your view using the technique in my answer?

Comment: yes i've tried i've used onclick ajax call jquery function to load the table..so i've to give this condition in that ajax call success condition..

Comment: Is it me or is `lstunutilizedownershipentities` extremely hard to read?

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that this code block runs always, you have to assert that. Easiest way would be to:

- before rendering the table, output your condition variable something like this`<p>@Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count</p>`
- look inside rendered HTML code in your browser (source code). If what you believe is happening, jQuery `ready()` code block should be rendered both when `Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count` is 0 and when it's not

If you confirm this, you've found a bug in Razor engine. Otherwise you could be having a bug somewhere around the place where your update your viewmodel.

Comment: How can i give the same if condition in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have **another** element in your HTML having `id="header"` (maybe in the Layout file).

Try this:

```
...
$("#header2").hide();
...
...
<thead id="header2">
...
...
```

If my solution doesn't work, try and check CSS for the `#header` element. Maybe, there is `display: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @model <-- this is your model 
    <table> 

       <tr style="text-align:center;">
        <label>No data is Available</label>
       </tr> 
    }   

    @{        

   if (Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities.Count ==0)
   {          
  <thead id="header">
  <tr>                
  <th style="width: 50%;">
     @Model.lstCommonLabels.lblCurrentOwnership
  </th>                
  <th>
    @Model.lstCommonLabels.lblCount
  </th>
 </tr>
 </thead> 
 }
 }


 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

@foreach (var item in Model.lstunutilizedownershipentities)
            {                    
                
                @item.CurrentOwnership
                @item.cnt
                
            }

Comment: @model is the model that youve pass into your view.